# Hyperlink In HTML in an ordered list

Tags: javascript, html

So I have to add a 5th item to this ordered list and the 5th item has to be hyperlinked. I am putting exactly what I am reading online and it is not working.

```
// create an ordered list
document.write("<ol>");
document.write("<li>Reduce spending on non-necessities.</li>")
document.write("<li>Use extra money to pay off debt,starting with the 
highest-interest credit card.</li>")
document.write("<li>Continue paying off debts until you are debt free.</li>")
document.write ("<li>Put a fixed percent of your pay aside in savings.</li>")
document.write ("<li> <a href="https://www.financial-planning.com/"> Financial Planning </a> </li>")
document.write("</ol>");
```

I get this error. "Parsing error: enexpected token https

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping `li` with single quotes:

```js
document.write ('<li> <a href="https://www.financial-planning.com/"> Financial Planning </a> </li>')
```

**OR:** With ES6 [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
document.write (`<li> <a href="https://www.financial-planning.com/"> Financial Planning </a> </li>`)
```

**OR:** You can escape the inner double quotes by prefixing `\`:

```js
document.write ("<li> <a href=\"https://www.financial-planning.com/\"> Financial Planning </a> </li>")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass " char as it is to write function. To do it you can use escape char () or single quote (')

```
document.write("<ol>"); 
document.write("<li>Reduce spending on non-necessities.</li>")
document.write("<li>Use extra money to pay off debt,starting with the highest-interest credit card.</li>")
document.write("<li>Continue paying off debts until you are debt free.</li>") 
document.write ("<li>Put a fixed percent of your pay aside in savings.</li>") 
document.write ("<li> <a href=\"https://www.financial-planning.com/\"> Financial Planning </a> </li>")
document.write("</ol>");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a string and you want to put quotes inside it, use double-quotes first and inside single-quotes:

```
"<li> <a href='https://www.financial-planning.com/'> Financial Planning </a> </li>"

'<li> <a href="https://www.financial-planning.com/"> Financial Planning </a> </li>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use single quotes on the outside.

Like so:

```
'<li> <a href="https://www.financial-planning.com/"> Financial Planning </a> </li>'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not formatted correctly. Remove the double quotes and add single around the address.

try the following:

```
"<li> <a href='https://www.financial-planning.com/'> Financial Planning </a> </li>"
```